# How to debug An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in unknown module

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, maui

My team and I run a dotnet maui app. Our main target is windows and we're deploying from windows VS to windows target for local development. During startup the app crashes... a lot... but without any useful stack traces, or debug info. I do not see any way to continue. Sometimes it pops up "Application in break mode" and gives the exception name and other times it doesn't even have the decency to do that.

Comment: (1) Delete solution’s hidden .vs folder, and all .obj and .bin folders. This ensures there isn’t something corrupted when build. (2) Run Debug Build with breakpoints in app.xaml.cs constructor and main page constructor. Step thru code and/or Add Debug,Writeline statements, to see how far it gets. (3) Wrap code in those constructors in try..catch, with Debug.Writeline in catch blocks. Does this help show where it went wrong?

Comment: (4) As a test, simplify the code run during startup. Comment out your code/xaml as much as possible, and make the first page shown only a label saying “got this far” (or whatever). Still crash? (4a) If not, good, you have a solid starting place. Start adding your real code back in. (4b) If still crashes, then make a new project, make sure it doesn’t crash. Start adding your code to new project, until it crashes.